# How to do intern URL masking ( Leave only the domain name )

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cakephp, dns, ubuntu-18.04

How can I do a full URL masking, for example my website looks like this :

https://website.com

I'm using CakePHP as a framework in a digital ocean droplet that uses (Apache2 / Ubuntu 18.04)

The path of the CakePHP directory : /var/www/html/websiteDir

When I visit my website the framework makes the link looks dynamic for example :

https://website.com/Controller/View

I wanna let the user click on links but show only the domain name, I don't want him to see the full URL

I'm forcing https redirection from http using .htaccess file  (PATH: /var/www/html/.htaccess)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        Options +FollowSymlinks
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website.com [OR] [NC]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.website.com [NC]
        RewriteRule .* websiteDir [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Any improvements to my .htaccess file or my virtual host file are welcome, please feel free

Comment: You don't want them to see the URL in the page content, or in the address bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are using the method `$this->Html->link()` to create the links. When you provide a single parameter (the url) like:

```
echo $this->Html->link(['controller' => 'Controller', 'action' => 'view']);

// Result:
// <a href="https://website.com/Controller/View">
//     https://website.com/Controller/View
// </a>
```

Using two parameters, the first is the text to display and the second is the url, this will result in:

```
echo $this->Html->link(
    Router::url('/', true),
    ['controller' => 'Controller', 'action' => 'view']
);

// Result:
// <a href="https://website.com/Controller/View">
//     https://website.com/
// </a>
```

And the user will only see the domain. Router is available with `use Cake\Routing\Router`.